# Pass data from Collection View Controller to View Controller using delegates

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, delegates, viewcontroller

On a button press, I am trying to send data from Collection View Controller to my View Controller. Here is what I have so far:

#### CollectionViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class CollectionViewController;

@protocol CollectionViewDelegate <NSObject>

-(void) sendTest;

@end
@interface CollectionViewController : UICollectionViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<CollectionViewDelegate> deligate;

@end
```

#### CollectionViewController.m

```
-(void) viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
}

...

NSLog(@"check");
[self.deligate sendTest];
NSLog(@"called");
```

#### FooViewController.m

```
#import "CollectionViewController.h"

@interface FooViewController () <CollectionViewDelegate> {}
@end

@implementation FooViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CollectionViewController *controler = [[CollectionViewController alloc] init];
    controler.deligate = self;
}

- (void) sendTest {
    NSLog(@"Delegates are great!");
}
```

Unfortunaly when I call `[self.deligate sendTest];` nothing happens. I know it is called, because I get the `check`, `called` logs.

Comment: `self.deligate` is probably nil when you call `sendTest`, because FooViewController got released. Having those NSLogs there tells you nothing. Use some breakpoints.

Comment: ok, thanks for the advice about the logs. Could you explain a little more about `self.deligate`? and maybe how to not have `FooViewController` get released? Thanks!

Comment: The delegate property "deligate" has a weak reference, which is good, but that means that the delegate needs to be retained by other object. I can think that maybe you dismissed FooViewController at some point, and then it is gone forever. Can you post more code? When are you presenting CollectionViewController?

Comment: The rest of the project has lots of other code in it and might make it more complex. Collection view controller is in a container view. Link to project: https://github.com/pudility/quick-things/tree/master/quickthings/src/components Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main wrong thing is that you are creating a `CollectionViewController` yourself, but you shouldn't. The CollectionViewController that you want is instantiated automagically by the Storyboard. How to find this view controller?

1 - Catch it during the segue in FooViewController:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    CollectionViewController *collectionViewController =(CollectionViewController *) segue.destinationViewController;
    collectionViewController.deligate = self;
}
```

2 - Find it in within the child view controllers in FooViewController

```
self.childViewControllers
```

Does it help you?